# How to get event of sent email & open, click counts in sendgrid using c#?

Tags: .net-core, c#-4.0, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I used the sendgrid's filters to filter messages and get count of open & clicks. But is there any other way to get that counts & events of sent email?

```cs
var queryParams ="(last_event_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP " + "'" + lastEmailSent + "'" + " AND TIMESTAMP " + "'" + date2 + "'" + ") AND from_email='" + From_Email + "' AND subject='" + myMessage.Subject + "'";

var client1 = new RestClient("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/messages?query="+ queryParams +"&limit=1");  
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);  
                client1.Timeout = -1;

                // var request1 = new RestRequestExecute();
                request.AddHeader("X-Query-Id", "{{X-Query-Id}}");
                request.AddHeader("X-Cursor", "{{X-Cursor}}");
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer API_KEY");
                
                IRestResponse response = client1.Execute(request);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Does anyone know how this could be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

You can receive events like opens and clicks live using the [Event Webhook](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event). There are 2 types of events - delivery and engagement events. Delivery events indicate the status of email delivery to the recipient. Engagement events indicate how the recipient is interacting with the email, such as opening or clicking on the email. Events are batched and then sent as an HTTP request to your designated endpoint and you can parse out the events that are important to you.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried  the Event Webhook but it only gives boolean values whether it is open or click(true/false) . I want actual open email & click email count of sent email. What is the way to approach this?

Comment: Either the way you are doing it, or by counting the number of open/click events that come through for an email.

Comment: Can we retain sent email details after 30 days from webhook as well 
 as sendgrid, because sendgrid keeps content of email for 30 days, whether it includes open, click counts also or not.

Comment: You can save and store that data for as long as your own policies allow.

Comment: I want to get live data of click & open counts of sent email from sendgrid? Is this possible to do?

Comment: You can get live events, as I've described above, or you can request the counts from the API as you were originally doing. I think you're asking for a combination of both, but that's not possible. If you use the live events you can store the current count yourself.

Comment: Yes, now I am clear about it. Thanks.